# Is it possible to have conditional declaration of methods and variables in templated classes?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to make a class that can have functions and members controlled by a template argument. I am thinking of something like this.

```
template<int control>
class ControlledDeclaration
{
public:
    if(1 == control)
        int Get() { return 0; }
    else if(2 == control)
        char* Get() { return "get"; }
    else if (3 == control)
        bool Get() { return true; }
};

void test_template()
{
    ControlledDeclaration<1> c_int;
    ControlledDeclaration<2> tx_int;
    ControlledDeclaration<3> b_int;
}
```

If possible, how to do it?

Comment: How bad would it be to specialize?

Comment: I think more than specialization what is involved is redesigning class hierarchy, abstracting the member containers to get uniform interfaces etc. There are about a dozen classes all with different templated containers e.g. vector, list etc. I am trying to control the declaration of them and few associated functions and take the easy way out this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I would use is along the lines of specializing the details in a traits class and provide the interface using the template. In this trivial example there isn't much benefit of using traits rather than specializing the actual type but in general customizing the few points of variations is easier using traits than specializations.

```
template <int> struct ControlDeclarationTraits;
template <>
struct ControlDeclarationTraits<1> {
    typedef int type;
    static int value() { return 0; };
};

template <>
struct ControlDeclarationTraits<2> {
    typedef char const* type;
    static char const* value() { return "get"; }
};

template <>
struct ControlDeclarationTraits<3> {
    typedef bool type;
    static bool value() { return true; }
};

template<int control>
class ControlledDeclaration
{
public:
    typename ControlDeclarationTraits<control>::type Get() {
        return ControlDeclarationTraits<control>::value();
    }
};
```

BTW, the type of string literals is `char const[n]` (for a suitable `n`) and not `char[n]`, i.e., you can't really use a string literal to initialize a `char*`. It does work because it was deemed necessary to support existing code to assign string literals to `char*` but it is actually a lie: trying to assign a value to any of the values causes undefined behavior. Making the pointer `const` makes it obvious that the content isn't meant to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html), that does exactly what you want.

Comment: SFINAE is kind of tricky in this context, as the members are not themselves templates.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas How tricky is it, really? You make them templates and SFINAE on return types.

Comment: Sorry, we don't use boost. Is there a non boost solution? Boost is way too complicated for me to read and understand, sorry.

Comment: @Dirt `enable_if` is trivial to [write yourself](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: @jrok: You need to change the function into a template, since there are no arguments, the compiler cannot deduce the type. In C++11 you can use a default template argument, but in C++03 you cannot have default template arguments for function templates so the user would have to provide the template argument for you. It would be easier to write a simple trait upfront or inheritance from a template base than than using SFINAE

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Ah yes, I forgot about default arguments.